# 08 Saturn Aura needs help

Tags: hvac, saturn, heat, aura

If I sit in my car with it idling the heat goes cold, but if I press the gas or drive off it heats back up. Can anyone help pinpoint this problem? Also, with engine running I can clearly hear fluid of some type circulating. What could this be and is it ok? Please help...08 Saturn aura

Comment: Is your coolant full?  If so, I would be looking at heater core valve, partially plugged heater core, or bad water pump.

Comment: Are you wanting it to be hot or cold?

Answer (score 1):

This is typical of coolant being low in the radiator-engine. Let the engine cool overnight, then remove the radiator cap to see if you need to add some coolant.

Depending on the type of radiator overflow system, checking the overflow bottle will not always reflect if the radiator is full, especially if there is a slow coolant leak somewhere. Check it at the radiator cap when the engine is COLD.